# Blocking proxies with .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, proxy, http-proxy

I'm using the below code to block proxy servers from accessing my website. However, it doesn't work at all as if there is nothing inserted. All rules in the .htaccess are working fine. I've cleared cache and tried several proxies, but still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, trying to use the exact same code and not being able to block any proxy.

I've read this other solution and I'm pasting it in case it works for you:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}     !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED-FOR}       !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED}         !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}                 !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}           !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}       !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}     !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}    !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}   !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}      !^$     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```